# Codeigniter login with facebook, getUser always return 0

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2

I searched here and in the web for my problem, but i didn't found any soluation, this make me crazy, i don't know whats the proplem.
the propble is, getUser() function always return 0.

**here the my library:**

```
include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook.php');

    class Fbconnect extends Facebook{

        public $user_id = null;
        public $user = null;

        function Fbconnect(){
            $ci =& get_instance();
            $ci->load->config('facebook',true);
            $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');
            parent::__construct($config);
            $this->user_id = $this->getUser();
            $me = null;
            if($this->user_id){
                try{
                    $me = $this->api('/me');
                    $this->user = $me;
                }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                    error_log($e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**and this is the controller**

```
function facebookRequest(){
        $this->load->library('fbconnect');
        $data = array(
            'redirect_uri' => base_url().'home/handleFacebookRequest',
            'scope' => 'email'
        );

        redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
    }

    function handleFacebookRequest(){
        $this->load->library('fbconnect');
        if($this->fbconnect->user){
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->fbconnect->user);

        }else{
            echo "Login operation faild, try again later";
        }
    }
```

**and i used a config file to store the appId and secrect**

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your plugin `APPPATH.'libraries/facebook.php'` (that i believe you downloaded from facebook) there is a function `errorLog($msg)`, this function logs the errors in php error log (or apache error log rather) If you don't want to hassle, with rewrting that to CI error logging, you can just echo that `$msg` and see if there are any errors. Debug accordingly.

If you haven't changed ANYTHING in the core files you downloaded, my bet is that your curl request in  `function makeRequest(args[..]`) needs a `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` set to  `false`, or rather this line:  `$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;` needs to be added

Comment: where i can add this line `$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;`

Comment: @MohamedNagy In your plugin you donwloaded, there is a function `makeRequest` inside  is a curl call. see it there. did you try with the error log??

Comment: ok, i did it and an exception appeared when i print `$e` : `CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host`